# Rails Simple Form Association for all possible objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I'm trying to setup `simple_form` for a product/cart scenario, but a little differently than the typical scenario.  My display needs to list ALL available products and have a qty input for each.  When saved, the cart_items should store `cart_id`, `product_id`, and `qty` only for those items which have a qty provided.  If it's blank or zero, it should not be added to `cart_items`

**Cart:**

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cart_items
  has_many :products, through: :cart_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cart_items
end
```

**Cart Items:**

```
class CartItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
end
```

**Products:**

```
class Products < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cart_items
  has_many :carts, through: :cart_items
end
```

I'm trying to have my form display such as:

`[  x  ] (Qty)  Product Name 
[  x  ] (Qty)  Product Name 
[  x  ] (Qty)  Product Name
[  x  ] (Qty)  Product Name`

I'm not sure how to get the extra field for qty using `f.association :cart_items, collection: Products.all()` , and I tried this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :cart_items do |fa| %>
    <%= fa.association :product, as: :select %>
    <%= fa.input :qty %>
<% end %>
```

But that only displays existing associations, and also displays the product in a select list whereas I'd like to just list out all products and display their associated qty.

Is there a nice and pretty "Rails-y" way of doing this that I'm overlooking, or do I need to do some more manual manipulation in my controller and views?  I'm using Rails 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that there is no special "Rails-y" way, or I am not aware of it. I think that you will have to loop over all your products and build cart_items for the missing ones before simple_fields_for tag. If a cart item with a product already exists then just show it; otherwise, build it first and then show.

You will also have to add rejection of cart_items in case of missing qty. Something like this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :cart_items, reject_if: lambda { |ci| ci[:qty].blank? || ci[:qty].zero? }
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you - that makes sense!  (removed previous side question here as I found the answer by googling)